# accessing parents table variable in childs table in primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng

I have two nested primeng p-tables,

```
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-data>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <p-table  [value]="phrTabs" dataKey="tabid">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-phrdata let-expanded="expanded">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{phrdata.tabname}} {{data.value}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
</ng-template>
```

I want to access data variable in my inner p-table but I'm using a different array for the table value and I cant seem to access data variable. Is there anyway I can declare in template or p-table so that I can use it in my inner table.